# ESP Unsubscribe Button generation & processing

Tags: marketing-cloud, unsubscriber

How does Marketing Cloud handle subscribers when they click the ESP system generated `This message is from a mailing list -- Unsubscribe` button at the top of some of our emails?

I was looking through the documentation but can't seem to find it.

We have a custom preference center and I most certainly imagine that that link doesn't send a programatic command to update the data extension.  My assumption is that it acts like a Global Unsubscribe at the parent level, but without digging into the data, I can't be sure.

**Basis of the question is really how to tie back subscribers that 'click' the link their mail client serves up when it says that 'this email is from a mailing list' -- to our Custom Preference Center data extension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsubs from this link are handled the same as auto reply unsubs via RMM where the status is changed inside the all subs or corresponding list/pub list.  You would need to reference status on the subscriber ([_ListSubscribers](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_listsubscribers.htm&type=5) DataView is likely best place) to tie it to your Custom Preference Center DE.

'List-Unsubscribe' uses 2 options, a mailto email address or a URL to auto unsub via the in-client button. [SFMC only uses the mailto option](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000228135&type=1), which means it basically runs it back via RMM and unsubs it from there.

I would likely recommend running a daily automation to query the listsub DV and then use those to update your DE accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about an unsubscribe link that your ESP is including, that's handled by the ESP itself.  You can usually download a list of recipients who clicked it.  (They do some pre-processing and prevent emails from going out to those addresses.)

If it's the recipients ESP you're talking about, many look at the **[List-Unsubscribe](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000228135&type=1)** information in the email header.  You can specify an "unsubscribe" mailto link, or an unsubscribe landing page URL.  The ESP will either send an email to the mailto link's address, or redirect the recipient to the landing page URL.

Of the biggest 3 ESPs (iOS mail, Gmail, and the various Microsoft-owned systems), all 3 support mailto responses.  Only Gmail supports redirect URLs.

I found instructions for setting the List-Unsubscribe header in Marketing Cloud Email Studio here:  **[Enterprise Reply Mail Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_perform_initial_configuration.htm&type=5)**

...and here's a description of how Gmail handles the List-Unsubscribe info on the Salesforce blog: **[Gmail's Unsubscribe Function: What You Need To Know](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2014/03/gmails-unsubscribe-function-what-you-need-to-know.html)**

Comment: Using Marketing Cloud.  Basis of the question is really how to tie back subscribers that 'click' the link their mail client serves up when it says that 'this email is from a mailing list' -- to our Custom Preference Center data extension